# Downloaded file is changed to ASCII-text file from type diff.gz

Tags: mac, safari

When I download a file of type `diff.gz` , the download file will become of `ASCII text` file. I have tried the option `Save As` to double check if the file extension appear correct. Still facing same issue. Could some one tell me what setting would do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Is `Open "safe" files after downloading` checked off in the General tab of Safari Preferences?

Below is a image from High Sierra.

[image]